# Create hex-representation of signed int in PHP

Tags: php, hex

I'm parsing a binary and stumbled upon some 16bit (2 byte) values that I need to convert from hex to dec and vice versa.
Positive values look like this "0075" (117) while negative ones look like that "FE75" (-395).

I'm using this function to convert from hex to signed int, which works, but I can't seem to find a solution for signed int to hex-representation.

```
function hexdecs($hex)
{
    // ignore non hex characters
    $hex = preg_replace('/[^0-9A-Fa-f]/', '', $hex);

    // converted decimal value:
    $dec = hexdec($hex);

    // maximum decimal value based on length of hex + 1:
    //   number of bits in hex number is 8 bits for each 2 hex -> max = 2^n
    //   use 'pow(2,n)' since '1 << n' is only for integers and therefore limited to integer size.
    $max = pow(2, 4 * (strlen($hex) + (strlen($hex) % 2)));

    // complement = maximum - converted hex:
    $_dec = $max - $dec;

    // if dec value is larger than its complement we have a negative value (first bit is set)
    return $dec > $_dec ? -$_dec : $dec;
}
```

Comment: [dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) ?

Comment: @hassan dechex doesn't work with signed INTs :-(

Comment: 'As PHP's integer type is signed, but dechex() deals with unsigned integers, negative integers will be treated as though they were unsigned. '

Comment: correct. I need to find a function that outputs "FE75" when I feed it "-395".

Comment: hmm - when I use 
dechex (hexdec("FFFF") - myDecimalNumber) 
I'm getting close enough, I guess....  :-/

Comment: You should use [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for signed number representation.

Comment: @LukasHajdu Thanks! That's looking promising. I find it rather hard to research such terms without knowing the name, thanks for pointing in that direction!!

Comment: `$value = -395; $packed = pack('s', $value); $hex=''; for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++){ $hex .= dechex(ord($packed[$i])); } var_dump($hex);`... but little/big-endian is machine specific

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your comments,
I ended up with this and it's just what I wanted.

You're awesome!

```
/**
 * Converts signed decimal to hex (Two's complement)
 *
 * @param $value int, signed
 *
 * @param $reverseEndianness bool, if true reverses the byte order (see machine dependency)
 *
 * @return string, upper case hex value, both bytes padded left with zeros
 */
function signed2hex($value, $reverseEndianness = true)
{
    $packed = pack('s', $value);
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++){
        $hex .= strtoupper( str_pad( dechex(ord($packed[$i])) , 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) );
    }
    $tmp = str_split($hex, 2);
    $out = implode('', ($reverseEndianness ? array_reverse($tmp) : $tmp));
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function DtH ($number, $bytes){
    $string = strtoupper(str_pad(dechex($number), $bytes, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
    $string = substr($string, -$bytes), 32);
    return $string;
}

echo DtH(-23715647, 8); //‭ FE9620C1‬

echo DtH(23715647, 8); //‭ ‭169DF3F‬

echo DtH(-23715647, 16); //‭‭ FFFFFFFFFE9620C1‬
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

For signed integer use `i` and `$i < 4;` instead of `s` and `$i < 2;`.

```php
/**
 * Converts signed decimal to hex (Two's complement)
 *
 * @param $value int, signed
 *
 * @param $reverseEndianness bool, if true reverses the byte order (see machine dependency)
 *
 * @return string, upper case hex value, both bytes padded left with zeros
 */
function signed2hex($value, $reverseEndianness = true)
{
    $packed = pack('i', $value);
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++){
        $hex .= strtoupper( str_pad( dechex(ord($packed[$i])) , 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) );
    }
    $tmp = str_split($hex, 2);
    $out = implode('', ($reverseEndianness ? array_reverse($tmp) : $tmp));
    return $out;
}

echo signed2hex(-1561800392, false); // 38d1e8a2, not 38d1 with `s`
```